# Is it possible to send SMS to a Data Extension using REST?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking a possible way to send SMS to a data extension using REST. I found out that we can send to list but cannot find possibility of sending to DE. I tried [this](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/getMessageList.html) but when I provide DE details (both in url or in json) it returns error. Any suggestion ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to send SMS directly to a data extension. However, you can do something very similar.

This REST call allows you to import a data extension into a MobileConnect list and send an SMS in the same call:  https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/importSend.html